# Developer Relations and Security API

Tags: facebook, security

We are working on a Facebook App that is security related.  We cannot post our question here due to security reasons.  Does anyone know how you can get in touch with Facebook's Development team?  Do they have a developer relations group?  If so, does anyone have an e-mail or contact?

Thank you - really appreciate any guidance and sorry this isn't your typical "stack" question, but we didn't know where else to turn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to file a bug that you can mark as confidential. It's no guarantee, however, that you'll receive a satisfactory response. 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

Post your question at developers.facebook.com.bugs and mark as confidential.